# Native javascript, handle click, change url

Tags: javascript

I need to handle click event for element on native js, After click, element url must be change, (i have one of query string parameter from current page url) and next, event handle will be continue (click on element having new link) (sorry I speak english badly).

simply put i want to do changes for element and execute native handle

```
function handle(e) {

var vin = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('vin');
    var item_url = this.getAttribute('href'); 

    if (!!vin) {
        var char = item_url.indexOf('?') != -1 ? '&' : '?';
        this.setAttribute('href', item_url + char + 'vin=' + vin);
    }
}
```

Comment: How you are calling this function `handle(e)`?

Comment: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
     var links = document.querySelectorAll('.category_link');
 for (i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
     links[i].addEventListener('click', handle)
 }
    });`

Comment: how i can format code in comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update `href` value on `DOMContentLoaded`. Remove `handle` function.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
    var vin = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('vin');
    if (!!vin) {
        var links = document.querySelectorAll('.category_link'); 
        for (i=0; i<links.length; i++) { 
            var item_url = links[i].getAttribute('href'); 
            var char = item_url.indexOf('?') != -1 ? '&' : '?';
            links[i].setAttribute('href', item_url + char + 'vin=' + vin);
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT 1**

If you want to do with handle then you should replace `this.setAttribute('href', item_url + char + 'vin=' + vin);` with `location.href = item_url + char + 'vin=' + vin`. Your `handle` function will be like below:

```
function handle(e) {
    var vin = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('vin');
    var item_url = this.getAttribute('href'); 

    if (!!vin) {
        var char = item_url.indexOf('?') != -1 ? '&' : '?';
        location.href = item_url + char + 'vin=' + vin;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But one problem - in sample i used ten html elements, but in the real project page have 1k+ target links for this handle on the page. That is why i want use handle for click event :)